# How do/can I charge a Li-po battery without a fancy charger (just using a current)?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I am designing a model airplane that flies using solar cells on its wings.  I have a 7.4 V, 2200 mAh battery I want to use for it in case it flies in a cloudy area and needs more power, but everywhere I look you need to use an expensive, bulky charger to charge it.

This is probably pretty basic but how can I charge it with a current from solar cells?

Comment: Doable with due care and design. Flag me if no other answers along those lines in next few days. || Important: What are panel spec :  Voc Vmp Imp Isc? | What are battery 
specs Vmax Vtyp How many cells Ah Ichg max, | motor  spec Voperate IMAX I cruise etc

Comment: What are the specifications of your solar cell array (eg. number of cells in series, output current, open circuit voltage)?

Comment: I agree it might be doable. I guess your battery pack is 2S. Please provide details of how many solar cells you have. If the battery voltage and solar cell Vmpp are close, you may just need an over-voltage cutoff to protect the cells. For example if you have 7 solar cells in series, plus an over-voltage cutoff, you can maybe just keep the solar cells connected directly to the battery. Oops. That is 7 solar cells per each battery. So 14 cells total.

Answer (score 11):

You need a proper charger to charge Li-po batteries safely, using the right algorithm; "just using a current" won't do and could damage the batteries.

For your purpose, you need a solar charge controller to match the solar panel to the battery, preferably an MPPT charger.

Such a charger doesn't have to be bulky. There are dedicated ICs and modules for exactly this purpose, like the [LT3652](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3652.html) and the [LTM8062](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltm8062.html); Adafruit has a [ready-made one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4755).

You can google around for other (pseudo-)MPPT solar battery charger ICs and modules that fit your specifications. You can make a charger with one of those that ticks all the boxes of a safe solar charger, but is still very small and light. It will also be fancy, but that can't be helped.

You should also add a cell-balancing BMS to your 2S battery pack, if it doesn't already have one. This also can be small and light.

Answer (score 8):

If you can keep the voltage of each cell individually to less than or equal 4.1V (4.0V safer still) then you can charge with current from solar panels.

If solar panel max current into battery is never less than manufacturer's maximum charge current then you do not need a current limiter.

You could charge the 2S 7.4V battery directly from the solar cells BUT each cell must have a maximum voltage limiter.

HOWEVER using a "proper" LiIon charger need not be expensive or complicated or bulky. To design correctly you need to know the parameters that I mentioned in a comment. If you don't know these then even a 'simple' solution is undesignable.

Panel specification

- Voc
  Vmp
  Imp
  Isc

Battery specification

- Vmax (8.2V?)
  Vtyp  (7.4V?)
  Number of cells (2?)
  Ah (2200 mAh?)
  Ichg max

Motor specification

- Voperate
  Imax
  I cruise

Answer (score 7):

With lithiums you need a battery management system.  No other choice.  If you don't want a BMS, use nickel metal hydride.

A BMS is a Battery Management System - it protects the battery from conditions which would damage it *or set it on fire*. However it is not burdensome, heavy or costly - it just requires a little knowledge you haven't acquired YET.

Look at any of the Youtube videos where people home-build lithium "power stations" out of piles of 18650 batteries. The BMS and balancer are the smallest parts.  Cheapest too.

And here's [Big Clive talking about basic 1-cell BMS's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M88e1r8nvYk) bought dirt cheap off eBay, and pointing out there's no earthly reason to dangerously hotshot them straight a supply such as a USB cord.

You certainly should buy a [ready-made BMS](https://www.ebay.com/itm/192110391518) and balancer, as you're in it to do your project... not re-invent the wheel.

Once you have the BMS in place to keep the battery from catching fire... I'm not overly concerned with the quality of your solar charge controller.  Is the additional power possible with an proper charge controller (or better: MPPT) *worth the weight*?  I leave such design decisions to you.

Comment: It is good to mention a BMS, but unless it is defined what it does, a BMS is completely separate entity from charging lithiums (proper charger needed) or using solar cells as supply (proper MPPT controller needed). A solar charger might contain BMS features or a BMS might be a feature of the battery pack if it is an exchangeable pack.

Comment: @Justme As long as a BMS is protecting the battery, I'm not overly concerned with the solar charge controller and I understand the desire to cut weight.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: It cannot be done safely or without damaging the battery. Why? because batteries have to go through a charge cycle with a constant current and then a constant voltage. This means you need a charger with a controller.

A solar cell cannot output a constant voltage on its own, this means a solar charge controller is needed.

The other problem is if you want to charge the battery fast, you will need to have a power supply that can source adequate current.

If you really want to charge a battery from solar cells you can look for a [solar charge controller](https://www.morningstarcorp.com/lithium-batteries/) that is compatible with lithium ion batteries (and probably a 2S) configuration.

Comment: The charge logic isn't *that* complicated. It's fairly doable to build from scratch. Most solar charge controllers won't be practical for use on an aircraft due to the weight. ..Although just buying a small one and stripping it down might actually work fine.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need a dedicated charger, but if you don't use one you will essentially have to build your own. A lipo charger needs to do the following things:

1. Limit the charge current to some value. Usually 1C, but for some batteries it can be up to 5C.
2. Limit the voltage to 4.2V per cell.
3. Manage each cell individually. It's not ok for instance to have one cell at 4.3V and the other at 4.1, even though the total is fine.

Here's an example of how you might do it (forgoing MPPT on the solar panels for simplicity):

- Power comes in from the solar panels, and you block it with a MOSFET
  or SSR.
- You monitor the total pack voltage, and the current using a current
  shunt.
- If the battery voltage is less that 4.2V per cell, turn on the
  mosfet.
- If the current rises above your current limit, PWM the mosfet gate to reduce the current.
- Use a dedicated BMS to keep the pack balanced. These are small PCBs often built into large lipo packs. They're not expensive.

Be careful, overcharging a lipo is a sure way to start a fire.

Answer (score 0):

You need circuit for limiting current and voltage. It is not too large, massive and expensive.
https://aliexpress.ru/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20221025042011&SearchText=lipo+charger+module&spm=a2g0o.productlist.1000002.0

Voltage of your battery 7.4 V. It means, you have serial connected cells. You need module for balancing voltage for avoiding exceeding maximum voltage on the individual cell.

You need BMS for two cells in series ( 2S ) and charger module.